# Rename enum item in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to change the name of an item in an enum type in PostgreSQL 9.1.5.

Here is the type's create stmt:

```
CREATE TYPE import_action AS ENUM
('Ignored',
'Inserted',
'Updated',
'Task created');
```

I just want to change 'Task created' to 'Aborted'.  It seems like from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertype.html), that the following should work:

```
ALTER TYPE import_action
RENAME ATTRIBUTE "Task created" TO "Aborted";
```

However, I get a msg:

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "import_action" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

But, it clearly does exist.

The type is currently being used by more than one table.

I'm being to think that there must not be a way to do this.  I've tried the dialog for the type in pgAdminIII, but there is no way that I can see to rename the it there.  (So, either a strong hint that I can't do it, or - I'm hoping - a small oversight be the developer that created that dialog)

If I can't do this in one statment?  Then what do I need to do?  Will I have to write a script to add the item, update all of the records to new value, then drop the old item?  Will that even work?

It's seems like this should be a simple thing.  As I understand it, the records are just storing a reference to the type and item.  I don't think they are actually store the text value that I have given it.  But, maybe I'm wrong here as well.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

In PostgreSQL version 10, the ability to rename the labels of an enum [has been added](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/10/588/) as part of the [ALTER TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-altertype.html) syntax:

```
ALTER TYPE name RENAME VALUE 'existing_enum_value' TO 'new_enum_value'
```

Comment: Do not forget to quote values ```alter type order_status rename value 'new' to 'draft'```

Answer (score 44):

**Update: For PostgreSQL version 10 or later, see the top-voted answer.**

Names of enum values are called labels, attributes are something different entirely.

Unfortunately changing enum labels is not simple, you have to muck with the system catalog:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-enum.html

```
UPDATE pg_enum SET enumlabel = 'Aborted' 
WHERE enumlabel = 'Task created' AND enumtypid = (
  SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'import_action'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  I'm wondering how good (or bad) of an idea this is.  It seems like if this were a safe operation, they would have a way to do this via a the ALTER TYPE stmt or via the pgAdminIII dialog.  That said, it seems (to me) that you *should* be able to do this.  I think it's just a label.  Any other comments?

Comment: @DavidS I don't see it as unsafe. It is more a matter that PostgreSQL developers have not added such a feature. (The ability to add a value, like in Catcall's answer, was only just added in 9.1.)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I didn't know that about ADD VALUE only being added in 9.1.  Thanks!

Comment: I've run the statement in your answer and it seems to have worked.  I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: The designers saw it as [something of a footgun](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2006-08/msg01008.php).

Comment: @Catcall The footgun comment refers to removing a value, but regardless, I don't think a 6-year old comment arguing against a feature, which has been partially implemented since that discussion, is relevant.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: The footgun comment refers to the question of "to add (or remove, or rename) elements of an enum type". The comment came from one of the original designers. I think the fact that it hasn't been implemented in the intervening years is telling.

Comment: @Catcall "Add, remove, or rename" includes add; and your answer below describes how to add an element to an enum type, so how can you say it hasn't been implemented? The reason Andrew called it a footgun is because, "we'd have to check every row to ensure we weren't orphaning some value", which is clearly referring to *removing* a value.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma: Removing and renaming hasn't been implemented. The OP wanted to rename a value.

Comment: @Catcall I know that. You wrote in your last comment that the designers were (six years ago) opposed to adding, removing, or renaming. Clearly, they are no longer opposed to adding, because they have indeed implemented it. Since they are no longer opposed to adding, there is no reason to believe they continue to be opposed to renaming, unless they have specifically said so recently. And, for the 3rd time, it is clear that the footgun remark is in regards to removing, because the explanation for the concern was "orphaned values."

Comment: @Catcall IMHO, if you can never add, rename or remove a value from an enum type, then the feature should go away.  What if the original dba/developer had a typo in one of the values?  Is it just suppose to be there forever?

Comment: @DavidS: Not that you asked, but I have never used enums in a database. I'm not yet convinced I need to. Onward . . . You *can* now add values. (Syntax is in my answer to the OP's question.) In the earlier [footgun link](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2006-08/msg01008.php), the designer says "the workaround [to removing and renaming values] is to create a new enum type and then do 'alter table alter column type ...' although I realise that could cause dependency problems too." Also see my answer for the quote and link from another designer about modifying values.

Comment: @Catcall - they are certainly not necessary.  You can accomplish the same by creating a table with a foreign key.  But, as I understand it, an enum is pretty much the same thing as having a table with a (id int, value_name varchar) structure.  If that's the case, then why would it be dangerous/bad to rename the value?  What am I missing here?  Your do you just not like the feature and don't think it should be used?

Comment: @DavidS: I don't know why it's dangerous. The implementation is not as simple as you might think. (I'll post [more links](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2008-04/msg01730.php) if I find them.) I don't have a problem with adding values to an enum, because there's language support for that. I think that usually a table is a better idea, and I don't like updating system catalogs myself. I mean, if it's *really* as simple as updating the catalog, surely they'd have implemented language support for it already.

Comment: @Catcall You seem to be twisting my words. I didn't say it was simple.  Or safe.  I asked a question. I got a response/recommendation from a user and I backed up my db and tried it.  It seems to have worked fine (for me).  If I got lucky, then I'm happy.  If you can post evidence that it's not, please do so (I would like to learn and hopefully it would benefit future users).

Comment: @DavidS: I'm not twisting your words. I'm just trying to explain what I've read from the designers, and why *I* don't use enums. (And why I wouldn't simply update the system catalog to change a value even if I *did* use enums.) All the enum issues are in the pg_hackers mailing list archive, but it's hard to find details and hard evidence. The short story is that the designers and Tom Lane had reservations about removing and renaming values, and they didn't implement it. When I see something like that, I step carefully. PostgreSQL source code might be worth reading.

Comment: @Catcall Twisting words is exactly what you are doing. "The short story is that the designers and Tom Lane had reservations about removing and renaming values." No, they had reservations about manipulating an enum in any way at all, including the ability to *add* values. You keep taking a 6 year old message out of context, repeatedly, and trying to put it in the context of today.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma and catcall you all are correct but this command need permission but i can't give permission, then what  to do with `ALTER`?

Answer (score 13):

The query in the accepted answer doesn't take into account schema names. Here's a safer (and simpler) one, based on http://tech.valgog.com/2010/08/alter-enum-in-postgresql.html

```
UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_enum
SET enumlabel = 'NEW_LABEL'
WHERE enumtypid = 'SCHEMA_NAME.ENUM_NAME'::regtype::oid AND enumlabel = 'OLD_LABEL'
RETURNING enumlabel;
```

Note that this requires the "rolcatupdate" (Update catalog directly) permission - even being a superuser is not enough.

It seems that updating the catalog directly is still the only way as of PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 7):

There's a difference between types, attributes, and values. You can create an enum like this.

```
CREATE TYPE import_action AS ENUM
('Ignored',
'Inserted',
'Updated',
'Task created');
```

Having done *that*, you can add *values* to the enum.

```
ALTER TYPE import_action 
ADD VALUE 'Aborted';
```

But the syntax diagram doesn't show any support for dropping or renaming a *value*. The syntax you were looking at was the syntax for renaming an attribute, not a value.

Although this design is perhaps surprising, it's also deliberate. From the [pgsql-hackers mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2006-08/msg00979.php).

> If you need to modify the values used or want to know what the integer
>   is, use a lookup table instead. Enums are the wrong abstraction for
>   you.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?  This is the only way enums are intended to work.  Manual modification of system catalogs is not to my liking.  And, to be clear, enums are quite unnecessary (the can be replaced by relational tools like tables and FKs on them).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Actually the quote from the mailing list is a bit out of context. It refers to the user wanting to get access to an enum's integer representation. As for altering the label the mailing list entry says: "Support for ALTER TYPE to allow adding / modifying values etc. For the time being you'll just have to create a new type, do a bunch of ALTER TABLE commands, DROP the old type and rename the new one if you want the old name back."